# OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor discord bot

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, discord.py

I am working on a discord bot using the discord.py API. I am trying to make the bot join a voice channel and play an mp3 file that is in the same directory. It joins the voice channel but prints the error in the title before playing anything. I was wondering what was causing this error. Relevant code below:

```
@client.command()
async def playClip(ctx):
    global voice
    channel=ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice= get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice= await channel.connect()

    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("BravoSix.mp3"))
    print("test")
    await voice.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the path you gave to the audio file is bad.
You have to give it the whole path to the file using single backslashes

```
voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("C:\whereever\the\file\is\BravoSix.mp3"))
```

Comment: I have tried both, the first gives me the same error. The second one gives me an error saying "C:\\filepath\\file" Protocol not found, Did you mean file: "C:\\Exact Same Filepath"

Comment: You might actually not have to use double backslashes but rather single backslashes